# Google Chrome "Force quit" issue and delay in keyboard typing and moving mouse pointer

Tags: dual-boot, google-chrome, performance, android-studio

So, I did a dual boot of Windows and Ubuntu for a Linux experience on my PC with 8GB RAM, Intel i3 processor, 128 GB SSD, and 1 TB HDD. I gave a 40 GB SSD partition for the root directory and 300+ GB for the home directory on Ubuntu.

Now, whenever I use Google Chrome, with no more than 3 new windows each with 5-6 tabs, the browser often freezes and asks to "force quit or wait". I disabled "Use hardware acceleration when available" and "run in background" as well as "Adblocker" extensions after searching for solutions, but they do nothing.

This freezing also happens for heavy apps like Android Studio. The most annoying thing in running Android Studio is that there is a delay in typing through the keyboard plus the mouse pointer freezes at one place after little movement. These bugs are so annoying compared to Windows because I don't even know where is the source of the problem before even looking for a solution.

So, please point me to the source and if possible a solution.

Comment: You will need to provide system information: this looks like it may be an issue with the graphics card.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)